# How can I customize "comment marker" in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

When setting the `formatoptions` to include the `o` flag, pressing `o` or `O` on a commented line will "inherit" the leading comment marker.

However, for `Stata`, only `\\` had been recognized as a "valid comment". The other two types of commenting had been ignored, by the `set formatoptions+=o`.

May I name multiple leading characters/strings to be the "comment marker" in Vim? Here goes how "comment lines" had been defined in the syntax file for `Stata`.

(From `C:/vim/vimfiles/syntax/stata.vim`)

```
" comments - single line
" note that the triple slash continuing line comment comes free
syn region stataStarComment  start=/^\s*\*/ end=/$/    contains=stataComment oneline
syn region stataSlashComment start="\s//"   end=/$/    contains=stataComment oneline
syn region stataSlashComment start="^//"    end=/$/    contains=stataComment oneline
" comments - multiple line
syn region stataComment      start="/\*"    end="\*/"  contains=stataComment
```

I don't see anything special about the `//` as a marker, at least in the syntax file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings you are looking for is the `comments` settings.

Since stata file don't appear to have a filetype plugin, nobody sets this and it stays at the default (which isn't very good).

Since stata comments are similar to c, we can look at how c handles the comments. In `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/c.vim` we find

```
setlocal comments=sO:*\ -,mO:*\ \ ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

If you add that to `~/.vim/ftplugin/stata.vim` you should have c style comments added to stata files. (This seems to handle all three types even though the leading `*` isn't a valid c comment.)

Relevant help topics `:h 'comments'` and `:h format-comments`. The second help topic will explain what all the options for `comments`.

Comment: Hi FDinoff, thank you for pointing out the C-style commenting method. However, it seems that my ~/ftplugin/ directory had not been sourced. In order to test your solution, I have made "setlocal formatoptions=ocq" and add the line you contributed. As of now, I cannot tell which goes wrong: when checking the formatoptions using ":set formatoptions", it only has "cq". Any thought on why the ~ftplugin had stopped to be sourced?

Comment: @linfeng you to have the path wrong. It should be `~/.vim/ftplugin` you forgot the `.vim` directory

Comment: thank you for your help and comments. I have found the source of the problem. To be explained in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787524/unable-to-change-foldingmethod-for-vim-from-marker-to-manual

Comment: Hi FDinoff, one more question though: how can I tell Vim that those lines starting with arbitrary number of "*" are also comment? I am a bit confused by the syntax used for the comments.

Comment: @llinfeng create a new question