# Unable to change foldingmethod for Vim from marker to manual

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

All of a sudden, my Vim starts with specifying `fdm=marker` regardless of the following two specifications

- In `_vimrc`, both in the beignning adn bottom, `set fdm=manual`;
- Per file type, have specified `set fdm=manual` through the `*.vim` files found in `~/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin`.

Same setting had been working well around a week ago, when I updated the `_vimrc`. However, I just notice today that "marker" had been speificed for no reason.

Any suggestion? I have tried to `Grep` all the presences of "marker" in the `~vimfiles` directory. This turned to be an unreasonable job to do, as there are thousands of presences of `marker`.

I have also tried to specify the following in my `_vimrc`, which did not work at all. 

`autocmd BufEnter * silent! set fdm=manual`

`fdm=manual` will always pop up regardless of what type of file I open, upon typing `set fdm` in the command line. (by pressing `:`).

I have just made my Vim available on Github under: https://github.com/llinfeng/Vim

All the best,

-Linfeng

Comment: If you are on windows the correct path for the vim settings would be `~/vimfiles/ftplugin` you seem to have an extra `vim` directory in your path. You can check where the `foldmethod` setting is being set with `verbose set foldmethod?`

Comment: I've found the source of problem, as could be found in my partial answer. By the way, I installed Vim directly under C disk on my machine. The full path to "ftplugin" is `C:\vim\vimfiles\ftplugin". In addition to this, there is another folder called "C:\vim\vim74" that is containing the "gvim.exe" + "*.dll" files. I also think that the directory structure also has to do with the installation package. (This should apply to Windows machines).

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer:

A plug-in called "restore_view.vim" is causing the problem. Upon uninstalling it, both settings I've tried did the work.

My guess is that, while `_vimrc` and "*.vim" files in `~/ftplugin/` did get sourced, the "restore_view" plugin will restore the "old view", which includes the folding methods and formatoptions, at the very end of the sourcing process. Therefore, all the previous settings of `fdm` and `formatoptions` had been restored and the newly implemented ones cannot be applied.

Here goes the github mirror of this plugin:
https://github.com/vim-scripts/restore_view.vim/blob/master/plugin/restore_view.vim

As a solution to my post, simply removing the plugin will solve all the issues. However, it remains to be an open question of how to properly deploy the "restore_view" plugin. I have emailed the author for suggestion and will also start a new question on Stack Overflow.