# How can I tell Vim that those lines starting with arbitrary number of "*" are also comment?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

This is a follow-up question for: [How can I customize "comment marker" in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665317/how-can-i-customize-comment-marker-in-vim/28665496?noredirect=1#comment46328298_28665496)

I noticed that through specifying the following for `Stata` filetype:

```
setlocal comments=sO:*\ -,mO:*\ \ ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
```

I can let Vim know that there are three various ways to mark a line as "comment".

However, for Stata specifically, `**` will also lead a line of comment. I think the current setting is recognizing the `*[A-Za-z]` and other type of comments with `*` starting a line by it self. May I let Vim "know" that line starting with arbitrary number of `*` is also a comment?

@FDinoff suggested me to open a new question here.

Comment: What is your intent on this?  To have vim comment out the lines using the '**'?  OR to have it show up in syntax coloring? When I open a `stata` file, it comments it out using the `/*%s*/` (the general default) but then will use the `**` after I `set commentstring=**%s`.

Comment: This was meant to make writing comments easier. With the improved setting of `comments` and `setlocal formatoptions=crnqj`, I am able to start a new line of comment if: 1) I am writing a "recognized comment" in insert mode; then 2) hit enter. However, Vim does not know that I am writing a comment even if I employed your suggestion globally. (Hit enter in a line leaded by `**`, for example.)

Comment: This is how it works for me: in insert mode, I start typing a line `*aa` and it's immediately recognized by vim as a comment; start line with `**aa` is same, plus `* aa` and `** aa` (with spaces) and `************* aa`.  All are recognized as comments when I start to type the lines. I tested this after starting `vim --noplugin` - is it possible one of your plugins is conflicting with this? Or that your chosen `colorscheme` is not showing them?  (I'm confused.)

Comment: Just reviewed the question you asked that this one was an offshoot from.  Do you have a 'state' filetype in your Vim install?  There are two in mine (SMCL, Stata).  If your vim is not recognizing the file type, then there will not be syntax highlighting.  Do you know that Vim is seeing this as type 'state'?  (try: `:set ft?`)

Comment: @Cometsong. Oh, Vim does display the comments correctly. By "recognize", I am referring to something other than the coloring. What I would like Vim to recognize is that `**` is a leader for comment and shall be conformed when generating a new line. This is triggered by setting the `formatoption=cor`, wherever applicable.

Comment: @Cometsong, for the sake of file type, my distribution of Vim does recognize the filetype as `stata`, and I have specified all the `Stata`-specific settings in a `stata.vim` file located in my run-time plugin folder. (For Gvim install on Windows OS, my directory is `~\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin`.)